# Implicit conversion to type with user defined operation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I would like to use the user defined operator for type which is inside a class:

```
class TWithUserDefinedOp
{
private: int a{42};
public: operator *(const TWithUserDefinedOp& other) { return a * other.a;}
};

class Wrap 
{
private: TWithUserDefinedOp a;
public: operator TWithUserDefinedOp() const { return a; }
}
```

Now when I would like to multiple the `Wrap` classes, I'd expect it to work

```
Wrap a, b;
auto mul = a * b; //Error: Wrap does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Now if I change the wrap to hold the integral type:

```
 class WrapIntegral 
 {
 private: int a{42};
 public: operator int() const { return a; }
 }
```

The multiplication now works.

```
WrapIntergal a,b;
auto mulInt = a * b; // this works ok
```

I have read in other similiar questions that `C++` only allows 1 level of implicit conversion. If I count correctly, there is just one implicit conversion in the first example. From `Wrap` to `TWithUserDefinedOp` for which the `operator *` is defined. What is my misunderstanding or what do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the op* has the signature: TWithUserDefinedOp operator* (const TWithUserDefinedOp& other). same for Wrap class.

this means that the first conversion is (Wrap -> TWithUserDefinedOp) and the second one expects (TWithUserDefinedOp -> Wrap).

a possible fix for your original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class TWithUserDefinedOp
{
private:
    int a{ 42 };
public:
    TWithUserDefinedOp(int a_ = 1) : a(a_) {}
    friend TWithUserDefinedOp operator* (const TWithUserDefinedOp& a, const TWithUserDefinedOp& b);
};

TWithUserDefinedOp operator* (const TWithUserDefinedOp& a, const TWithUserDefinedOp& b)
{
    return TWithUserDefinedOp(a.a * b.a);
}

class Wrap
{
private:
    TWithUserDefinedOp a;
public:
    Wrap(const TWithUserDefinedOp& a_ = TWithUserDefinedOp()) : a(a_) {}
    operator TWithUserDefinedOp() const
    {
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Wrap a, b;    
    auto c = a * b;
    cout << typeid(c).name() << "\n";   // TWithUserDefinedOp
    Wrap d = a * b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you need a conversion from your class type to an Integral type, which is the predefined one for Multiplication operator. In your first example you don-t have it.

Comment: I have defined the multiplication operator for it, which should be sufficient. Thne it comes to multiplying integral types internally.

Comment: You have defined multiplication operator for TWithUserDefinedOp, not for Wrap